# casting a base generic class from a derived generic class in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I need to find a way to retrieve properties from an instance of a generic class, where the generic argument type is a derived class. 
For example:

```
Class A 
{
    public int data;
}

Class B : Class A { }

Class C : Class A { }

Class D : Class A { }

.
.
.

Class G<T> 
{
    T field
}

main()
{
    object t = CallOuterService();
}
```

given that t is an instance of G instantiated with one of the deriving classes, is there a way to access data field without trying to cast to all the deriving classes?

*edited - 
1. data field is public
2. classes A, B, C... G are not handled by my code, they are all interfaces with an external service. I can't edit them in any way...

Comment: just use `public int data;`, what return `CallOuterService` and why you assign it to `object`?

Comment: It would really help if you'd show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem rather than just pseudocode.

Comment: _classes A, B, C... G are not handled by my code, they are all interfaces with an external service._ so it classes or interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

Through [covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) you could:

```
class A
{
    public int data;
}

class B : A { }

class C : A { }

class D : A { }

interface IG<out T>
{
    T field { get; }
}

class G<T> : IG<T>
{
    public T field { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
G<D> gd = new G<D> { field = new D { data = 5 } };

IG<A> ga = gd;
int data = ga.field.data; // 5
```

Note that you can only read the `field` property, not write it! And covariance is only for interfaces (for this reason I had to define a `IG<T>` interface and use it to access the `field` property)